# ASP.NET MVC Login with Facebook requires review

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using the out of box ASP.NET MVC template but login with Facebook seems to be asking "Submit for Login Review". This is all I am asking for:

```
var options = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions();
options.AppId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Facebook.AppId"];
options.AppSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Facebook.AppSecret"];
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(options);
```

The above code will set `scope=public_profile&email` when calling `https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/oauth`. As per Facebook's documentation, none of this should require review.

Does ASP.NET MVC authentication with Facebook using above code always require Login Review from Facebook?

Comment: It looks like FaceBook might have updated their authentication policy to require review for machine initiated login.